# How to return form values in Angular?

Tags: angular, forms

i've built a simple page in angular which gets some data from a webservice, puts it into variables, and displays them in text boxes (and one check box) and now I need to pass the values of those controls into a function when I click a submit button. I have found a few examples on the web but most either don't work or are too complicated for my needs as a beginner.

I have added a form around my controls like this:

```
<form #policydetails="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onClickSubmit(policydetails)">

</form>
```

And I have added `ngModel` to each of the input controls. In my ts file I have an interface:

```
interface policyDetails {
 surveyChecked: boolean;
  title: string;
  name: string;
  address1: string;
  address2: string;
  address3: string;
  address4: string;
  address5: string;
  postcode: string;
  telephone: string;
  telephone_work: string;
  telephone_mobile: string;
  email: string;
  policy_no: string;
}
```

And my onClickSubmit function looks like this:

```
onClickSubmit(policydetails: policyDetails) {
  alert(policydetails.title);
}
```

This seems like it should work, but when I serve the site I get this:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR

src/app/app.component.html:4:59 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'NgForm' is not assignable to parameter of type 'policyDetails'.
  Type 'NgForm' is missing the following properties from type 'policyDetails': surveyChecked, title, address1, address2, and 9 more.

4   <form #policydetails="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onClickSubmit(policydetails)">
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong? Please try to keep your answer clear and simple as i'm very new to Angular. Thanks!

Comment: `onClickSubmit(policydetails.value)` the "policydetails" is the [ngForm](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm) that has severals properties

Answer (score 0):

You can remove ="ngForm" as it is the wrong syntax. you can do #policydetails for policydetails to be your id. Try this

```
<form #policydetails (ngSubmit)="onClickSubmit()">

</form>
```

This will give you an empty form that submits to nothing, then you can use some angular **FormControl**, to keep track of your data. You can go to  [Angular form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) for the full documentation.

Comment: Zepse, I love Reactive Forms because we can check errors and mannage a form in a beauty and compact way, but the question is about ngForm -Template driven forms-.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say I'm a little disappointed at the response to this, given that it's such a basic task for an angular developer. In any case, I've managed to find a solution by myself. I made a small tweak to the form from:

```
<form #policydetails="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onClickSubmit(policydetails)">

</form>
```

to:

```
<form #policydetails="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onClickSubmit(policydetails.value)">

</form>
```

I also had to change the inputs from:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ title }} " name="title" ngModel>
```

to:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" name="title" />
```

Anyway, thanks [Zepse Wolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19399885/zepse-wolf) and [Eliseo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8558186/eliseo) for trying. Hopefully this might help others trying to get to grips with angular.

Comment: Really is not exact, althought it's better use [(ngModel)] you can not use

Answer (score 0):

Some points to the response to the question (It's only as curiosity because really the best bet is use [(ngModel)], or Reactive Forms

Really you can use only ngModel in the way

```
  <input name="first" ngModel required>
```

(no need `[(ngModel)]`).

If you want to know if the input is touched or has errors you can use a template reference variable:

```
<input name="first" ngModel required #first="ngModel"> 
<span *ngIf="first.errors && first.touched">Required!!</span>
```

To give value you can use the own "ngForm" in the way, e.g.

```
  //get the ngForm
  @ViewChild('policydetails',{static:true}) ngForm:NgForm

  
  @ViewChild('policydetails') ngForm:NgForm

  ngOnInit()
  {
    //it's necesary enclosed in a setTimeout because 
    //Angular "create the ngForm" after paint it
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.ngForm.setValue({first:'first',last:'last'})

    })
  }
```

see [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mlwtyn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

But, really **is good practice** use `[(ngModel)]` in each input

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="first" name="title" />
```

And, as the answer indicate, if we use [(ngModel)] **never** use `value` (or `checked` if is a checkbox). Simply give value to the variable